# PowerShell: Get all items where column equals a certain value

Tags: powershell

I have a SharePoint site which I want to search all document libraries where `column1 = 'hello'` and then print out the columns `title, scope` and `column1`. Then output the result to a file.

I want to do this in a PowerShell script. I'm not sure how to go about this, this is the start:

```
Get-SPSite mysite |
Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
Select -ExpandProperty Fields |
Select Name, Scope, Column1 | Out-File test.txt
```

I am not sure how to do the where clause, I've seen `where` and `where-object`, Iäm confused how to do the where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where clause should be use in this way (this code has not been tested):

```
Select -ExpandProperty Fields | Where $_.Column1 -eq 'hello' | Select Name, Scope, Column1
```

BTW your code is wrong because `SPSite` has not `Lists` property. That property is in `SPWeb`