# site column where clause sharepoint

Tags: powershell

I have a sharepoint site and am creating a powershell script that searches through all document libraries and output the results based on a query to a site column.

```
Get-SPSite mysite
Select -ExpandProperty AllWebs |
Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
Select -ExpandProperty Fields |
Where $.PM -eq 'R' -or 'C' |
Select Name, Scope, PM |
Output-File outputpm.txt
```

This does not output anything for PM, yet I've been told its a site column.
Have I done my query wrong?

Comment: You are iterating over the fields and not the list items as it looks!

Comment: I thought that was it how do I iterate over the items then?

Comment: You shoud expand "Items" instead of "Fields". Not sure you will reach your column "PM" on the dot notation in the line after either. Might need to use the ["PM"]

Comment: I answered to you at the following link: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96876/powershell-get-all-items-where-column-equals-a-certain-value/96878#96878

Comment: which didn't work